# How does this import statement work?

Tags: javascript, import, vue.js

I just downloaded a template from a vue cli as
`vue init webpack my-project`.
and inside Hello.vue I saw an import statement like this.
`import Hello from '@/components/Hello';`

and I am curious what does that `@` does. It's used at a lot of places but no where it's written what exactly it does. Would be great if someone can explain what it does? and how it is different from a normal import?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in the project at webpack.base.config.js for the webpack template vue-cli creates, you can see there is an alias set:

`'@': resolve('src')`

See: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/blob/develop/template/build/webpack.base.conf.js

Line 27.

So it's just to make it easier to load modules. So you dont need to type things like `import 'component from '../../../src/components'` you can just type '`@/components`'.

So it it just for convenience. There is no difference in functionality to a regular import.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writting the following statement:

import Hello from '@/components/Hello';

In this statement **@ means that, it will load the correspondes package and import class,variable and methods into your component.**

Comment: How is it different from a normal import?